# My leopard gecko keeps burrowing but not like in sand

Tags: behavior, safety, leopard-geckos, containment

My leopard gecko (I think it's a female but I'm not sure) keeps burrowing herself under things. It started with burrowing under her reptile carpet so I secured it, then under a heavy rock which I errorneously assumed was to get a hiding cricket, and then I got concerned when I heard her moving so I went to check and she had wedged herself under her very heavy water dish and I thought she was dead! Luckily she's OK but I keep hearing her digging all through the night and can't sleep because I'm afraid she'll hurt herself.

**What should I do? I'm getting her a better, new cage soon but I don't know what to do in the meantime.**

Comment: Sounds like it searchs for a hide, there are different reasons you should find out. Feels safe or cooling are in my mind first.

Answer (score 1):

Does she have sufficient hides (at least 2 with one being a moist hide)? If not, she is probably just trying to hide. If she does, digging is a natural behaviour. Consider either replacing the reptile carpet with a loose substrate or providing a dig box (a box full of loose substrate). I use Arcadia EarthMix Arid in my leopard geckos enclosure.